# Feymann Kac pde with correlated process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, sde, wienerprocess, feynman-kac

I have to solve the following PDE:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x\partial y}+y=0\\\\
F(t,x,y)=e^{x+y}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
In principle I assume that there exist two independent $\mathbb{P}$-Brownian motions $W^1$ and $W^2$ such that:
\begin{equation}
dX_t=\sigma_1dW^1_t\\\\
dY_t=\sigma_2(\rho dW^1_t+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}dW^2_t)
\end{equation}
Looking now at the coefficients of the PDE we have that $\sigma_1=1$, $\sigma_2\rho=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sigma_2^2(1-\rho^2)=1$. From this we get $\rho=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $\sigma_2=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Hence substituting in the previous I get:
\begin{equation}
dX_t=dW^1_t\\\\
dY_t=\frac{1}{2}dW^1_t+dW^2_t
\end{equation}
From which I obtain the dynamics:
\begin{equation}
X_T=X_t+(W^1_T-W^1_t)\\\\
Y_T=Y_t+\frac{1}{2}(W^1_T-W^1_t)+(W^2_T-W^2_t)
\end{equation}
Applying now Feymann Kac formula I get:
\begin{equation}
F(t,X_t,Y_t)=E(e^{X_T+Y_T})+\int^T_tE(Y_s)ds=E(\exp(X_t+\sqrt{T-t}Z_1+Y_t+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{T-t}Z_1+\sqrt{T-t}Z_2))+Y_t(T-t)
\end{equation}
where $Z_1,Z_2$ are independent standard gaussian. Now solving the first expected value I get:
\begin{equation}
F(t,X_t,Y_t)=e^{X_t+Y_t+\frac{13}{8}(T-t)}+Y_t(T-t)\Rightarrow F(t,x,y)=e^{x+y+\frac{13}{8}(T-t)}+y(T-t)
\end{equation}
Now if I plug the solution into the pde I find that it doesn't work. Can someone tell me if the computation is fine or not?